# Count matches in different stdclass objects

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I've got an array of data containing stdClass Objects that looks like this if I do `print_r($data['exam_scores'])`:

```
[exam_scores] => Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 2
[student_id] => 656
[student_session_id] => 989
[session_id] => 16
[class_id] => 1
[section_id] => 1
)

[1] => stdClass Object
(
[student_id] => 656
[student_session_id] => 989
[session_id] => 16
[class_id] => 1
[section_id] => 1
)

[2] => stdClass Object
(
[student_id] => 231
[student_session_id] => 989
[session_id] => 16
[class_id] => 2
[section_id] => 1
)

[3] => stdClass Object
(
[student_id] => 114
[student_session_id] => 989
[session_id] => 16
[class_id] => 2
[section_id] => 1
)
```

I want to count the number of occurrences of `class_id` and `section_id`.

That is, if the first object's `class_id` and `section_id` matches with the next object's, then count, and so on.

Also note that where the `student_id`  matches with the next object, count as 1

This is my expected output
where `class_id` and `section_id` is one, count is **1** (`student_id` is the same
where `class_id`=2 and `section_id`=1 then count is **2**

I have no idea how to begin this one...
Please help

Comment: Do the objects have different structures (one with [id] and four without) or is it a careless mistake? Then please be more exactly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a simple question but a task that is usually solved by databases using SQL.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT student_id) AS count_students 
WHERE class_id=2 AND section_id=1
FROM ... ;
```

Doing this with arrays is a complex task.

Take a look at [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and create a filter function for your conditions (class_id=2 and section_id=1). With [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) you get the student_id column as a one-dimensional array. With [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) you remove all duplicate entries and then count them with count().

For each of these steps, you can find solutions here on Stackoverflow.

I checked the proposed solution with a special class.

```
$exam_scores = [
  // :
];

$data = TableArray::create($exam_scores)
  ->filterEqual(['class_id' => 2, 'section_id' => 1])
  ->fetchColumnUnique('student_id')
;

var_dump($data,count($data));
/*
array(2) { [0]=> int(231) [1]=> int(114) }
int(2)
*/
```